# Android Studio Bouncy castle issue (newbie)

Tags: android

I am trying to run my first simple webview app, unfortunately I know very little able Java. I am following along with the Android getting started guide:
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/gettingstarted#add_the_webview

When trying to compile and run the app I am receiving this error:

```
Gradle tasks [:MyCustom:assembleDebug]
Execution failed for task ':MyCustom:packageDebug'.
> class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

Im running:
OSX 10.9.1

```
Java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

.bash_profile
export JAVA_HOME=“/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home”
```

Is there anything else I should be looking at?

UPDATE:

```
Here is the error:
Executing tasks: [:MyCustom:generateDebugSources]

:MyCustom:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:prepareDebugDependencies
:MyCustom:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.907 secs
Executing tasks: [:MyCustom:assembleDebug]

:MyCustom:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:prepareDebugDependencies
:MyCustom:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:MyCustom:validateDebugSigning
:MyCustom:packageDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MyCustom:packageDebug'.
> class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.   (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to  get more log output.
```

Comment: seems like you are trying to override a final method

Comment: Any idea how I can debug to find out what method that is?

Comment: More info
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    1.7.0_51, x86_64: "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-462, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: seems like class `ASN1Primitive` is overriding final `equals` method of java.lang.Object. Could you maybe post the code of this class?

Comment: I just deleted both the Jar bouncycastle files from the extensions folder and it fixed it.

Comment: Where did you find those jar files? I have the same stack trace failing at `:app:packageDebug` but I cannot find those jar files.