# Android Studio on Mac OS X, Gradle complaining about org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, bouncycastle

Recently migrated (or still trying to) from Eclipse ADT to Android Studio, here's what Gradle says when I hit `Run' (full trace below):

> ```
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> > class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
> ```

I've seen:  [Android Studio Bouncy castle issue (newbie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392675/android-studio-bouncy-castle-issue-newbie), [Problems launching error in Android Studio when packageDebug at Max OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579372/problems-launching-error-in-android-studio-when-packagedebug-at-max-os-x?rq=1) and similar SO posts that all point out to a bouncy castle JAR (`bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar`) that should be removed from the classpath. However I have no such JAR file there and it, in fact, Gradle itself seems to download it because the only place where I found it was:

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/
```

Trying to delete the file there, Gradle complains that a referenced library is missing.

Just how do I fix this?

---

Complete trace:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.479 secs
```